# How to move CCSprite

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I need to move sprite from side to side. I use:

```
CCSprite *man;

id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(20,300)];

[man runAction:actionMove];
```

When it's moved to (20,300) I need to move sprite to (20,0) and then move it to (20,300) and back.
How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Than accept an answer, pls.

Answer (score 7):

```
CCMoveTo *move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(20,300)];
CCCallFuncN *move_done = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished)];
[man runAction:[CCSequence actions:move1,move_done1,nil]];

-(void)spriteMoveFinished
{
    CCMoveTo *move1 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(20,0)];

    [man runAction:[CCSequence actions:move1,nil]];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if I got you right, but this should move your man 300 px on the y axis up and then back to 0 px on that same axis again in 2 seconds.
Not depending where is was before the man will move +300 on y and then -300 on y.

This is with CCMoveBy:

```
CCAction *moveOne = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(0, 300)];
CCAction *moveTwo = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(0, -300)];
CCSequence *manMoving = [CCSequence moveOne, moveTwo, nil];
[man runAction:manMoving];
```

This is with CCMoveTo:

```
CCAction *moveOne = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(20, 300)];
CCAction *moveTwo = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(20, 0)];
CCSequence *manMoving = [CCSequence moveOne, moveTwo, nil];
[man runAction:manMoving];
```